# Map JSon property to variable inside JSon string?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net, deserialization

I'm looking for a way to map multiple properties to different "sections" of a JSon string using newtonsoft.

What I currently have is the following (doesn't work at all, but maybe you'll get a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
public class example
{
  [JsonProperty("this.is.an.example")]
  public string ex { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("this.is.another")]
  public string ex2;
}
```

While the corresponding JSon string might be structured like so:

```
{
  "this" :
  {
    "is" : {
      "an" : {
        "example" : "this is the first value I want to return"
      }
      "another" : "this is the second value"
    }
  }
}
```

I want it this way so that I can easily deserialize several of these JSon strings like so:

```
example y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<example>(x);
//where x is the JSon string shown above and
//y.ex == "this is the first value I want to return"
//y.ex2 == "this is the second value
//Also note that example is the class name of the resulting object
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks in advance for any help, any input is appreciated!

**Note:**

After a bit of searching I found a similar question that didn't receive an answer. But maybe it'll help [JSON.NET deserialize/serialize JsonProperty JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146937/json-net-deserialize-serialize-jsonproperty-jsonobject)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `dynamic` keyword, instead of writing some complex code for custom deserialization.

```
string json = @"{""this"":{""is"":{""an"":{""example"":""this is the first value I want to return""}}}}";
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
string example = jObj.@this.@is.an.example;
```

*PS: Since `this` and `is` are reserved-words in c# I used `@` in front of them .*

Comment: I thought about this.. I'd prefer to have an object that I could just deserialize to, though.

Comment: I say this because the json that I'm dealing with can be hundreds of thousands of lines long (an object I don't feel like creating every time I want to deserialize)

Comment: Just realized that was my bad (I had been working on two similar deserialization codes and mixed them up a bit) I edited the question to reflect what my actual issue is. Sorry about that!